# Breakpoint isn't hitting in WinDBG

Tags: c#, debugging, windbg, breakpoints

There is a simple program in C #:

```
namespace Stack_and_call_x86
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int result = Add(2,4);
        }

        static int Add (int a, int b)
        {
            int answer = a + b;
            return answer;
        }
    }
}
```

I wrote and compiled it in MVS 2019. I'm trying to debug it in WinDbg. It seems that I’m doing everything right, I registered the paths to the symbols, I indicated the location of the .cs file, I use the Launch executable program. (I'm using the .exe from the Debug folder). I put a breakpoint:

**bp Stack_and_call_x86! main**

It produces the following:

```
WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for Stack_and_call_x86.exe
Operation not supported by integrated managed debugging.
error at 'Stack_and_call_x86! main'
The breakpoint expression "Stack_and_call_x86! Main" evaluates to the inline function.
Please use bm command to set breakpoints instead of bp.
```

OK, I put bm:

**bm Stack_and_call_x86! main**

Well, it seems to be set:

```
1: <MSIL: 00ca0000> @! "Stack_and_call_x86! Main"
```

Then, run and get the following error:

```
ModLoad: 75e20000 75e99000 C: \ WINDOWS \ SysWOW64 \ ADVAPI32.dll
Breakpoint 1's offset expression evaluation failed.
Check for invalid symbols or bad syntax.
```

P.S.

If I open the .cs file through File - Open Source File, and there  put a breakpoint in the code, then it is set, but when I start it, I get an error:

Unable to insert breakpoint 0 at 00ca0001, Win32 error 0n998
    "Invalid attempt to access memory address."
bp0 at 00ca0001 failed

Comment: For managed code, you should rely on sos. It has a `!bpmd` method that works with managed methods.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen, yeah, thanks, I have already understood about that. Now I am using sosex.

Comment: And so, you were able to answer your question?

Comment: !sos.bpmd and !sosex.mbp are the easiest options. However, with a little manual work you can still use bp. Use !sos.name2ee Stack_and_call_x86.exe!Stack_and_call_x86.Program.Main to find type details. If it is jitted, you can then use bp <jitted address> to break on it. If it has not yet been jitted, you can use !sos.dumpmt -md <MethodTable address> to find the MethodDescr, followed by !sos.bpmd -md <MethodDescr address>.

Answer (score 1):

For me the next steps are working:

1. Download the sosex.dll
2. In WinDbg:

   2.1. Open executable

   2.2. Write the following commands:

   - sxe ld clrjit
   - g
   - .load C:\SOSEX\sosex.dll (your path to sosex.dll)
   - !mbp Program.cs 14 (Your Name.cs file and line where you want to
     insert breakpoint)
   - g